# Retrieve BAID from PayPal Recurring Payment

Tags: paypal

Wondering if there's a way to retrieve the Billing Agreement ID from Payment via PayPal API? That is, associate a customer w/ a payment? The scenario is that I retrieve a list of payments that have been made for the day. For example,

```
oPmtHistory = Payment.List(oApiContext,....)
```

and from the list of payments in the `PaymentHistory` object, I can determine what payments belongs to which customers. Retrieving the payer in the Payment object doesn't appear to be the most reliable way to get the customer associated w/ a payment.

Comment: Please explain your last sentence. Being the payer from the payment is exactly how a customer who pays you is associated w/ a payment; why are you claiming this is not the way to get the payer?

Comment: Hello, I didn't claim that this is not a way to get a payer. I was suggesting that the payer may not a solid way to determine whom the actual customer is. For example, a customer may pay the balance w/ the currently stored credit card and then change to another credit card for future payments. Then, using the payer info, in this credit card may not be the most reliable way to associate w/ an agreement.

Comment: Ah. The PayPal account is one way for a customer to do this (since it can contain many paying instruments). You need to decide either to use PayPal accounts as your account mechanisms (which PayPal has explicit products to support, e.g. Login with PayPal) or you build your own customer account and simply attach payment instruments (which can be either PayPal accounts or cards, or other things)  within the account. Most people do the latter. But then you are responsible for maintaining the relationship between YOUR account structure and the payment instrument.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help. It's appreciated!